# Compare elements of two pandas data frame columns and create a new column based on a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1:

| ID | PersonID | Sex |
|:--:|:--------:|:---:|
|  1 |    123   |  M  |
|  2 |    124   |  F  |
|  3 |    125   |  F  |
|  4 |    126   |  F  |
|  5 |    127   |  M  |
|  6 |    128   |  M  |
|  7 |    129   |  F  |

df2:
| ID | PersonID | Infected |
|:--:|:--------:|:--------:|
|  1 |    125   |   True   |
|  2 |    124   |   False  |
|  3 |    126   |   False  |
|  4 |    128   |   True   |
```

I'd like to compare the person IDs in both these dataframes and insert the corresponding Infected value into df1 and False if the personID is not matched. The output would ideally look like this:

```
df1:
| ID | PersonID | Sex | Infected |
|:--:|:--------:|:---:|:--------:|
|  1 |    123   |  M  |   False  |
|  2 |    124   |  F  |   False  |
|  3 |    125   |  F  |   True   |
|  4 |    126   |  F  |   False  |
|  5 |    127   |  M  |   False  |
|  6 |    128   |  M  |   True   |
|  7 |    129   |  F  |   False  |
```

I have a for loop coded and it takes too long and is not very readable. Is there an efficient way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: The value of `Infected` column of person 124 is `False` in `df2` but `True` in the matched dataset. Is it a mistake or based on certain logic?

Comment: It was a mistake. Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to provide `df1['PersonID'].map()` with a Series whose index is `PersonID` and values are `Infected`:

```
df1['Infected'] = df1['PersonID'].map(df2.set_index('PersonID')['Infected']).fillna(False)
```

Comment: @RushilZutshi, great to hear!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `pd.merge`

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['PersonID', 'Infected']], on=['PersonID'], how='left').fillna(False)
```

Or

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2[['PersonID', 'Infected']], on=['PersonID'], how='left').fillna(False)
```